# Remove all instances of a character after a specific substring in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string

I have a column of character data in a Python/pandas dataframe with non-uniform underscores.  How do I remove all instances of "_" *after* the substring "ESP".  For example:

```
AProj_AB_ESP20211124125639

AProj_AB_ESP_20231017_205105

AProj_AB_ESP2021__1117132530

AProj_AB_ESP_20211123215423
```

Would return:

```
AProj_AB_ESP20211124125639

AProj_AB_ESP20231017205105

AProj_AB_ESP20211117132530

AProj_AB_ESP20211123215423
```

I've tried hacking around with the regex but I can't figure it out.  The closest I could get with ChatGPT prompts was `.str.replace(r'(?<=ESP)_', '')` but that doesn't quite do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex with a negative lookahead:

```
df['out'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'_(?!.*ESP)', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                            col                         out
0    AProj_AB_ESP20211124125639  AProj_AB_ESP20211124125639
1  AProj_AB_ESP_20231017_205105  AProj_AB_ESP20231017205105
2  AProj_AB_ESP2021__1117132530  AProj_AB_ESP20211117132530
3   AProj_AB_ESP_20211123215423  AProj_AB_ESP20211123215423
```

##### regex

```
_         # match _
(?!.*ESP) # only if not followed by ESP
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJ5FKd/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom replace function in `.str.replace`:

```py
df["Column1"] = df["Column1"].str.replace(
    r"(.*ESP)(.*)", lambda g: g.group(1) + g.group(2).replace("_", ""), regex=True
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                      Column1
0  AProj_AB_ESP20211124125639
1  AProj_AB_ESP20231017205105
2  AProj_AB_ESP20211117132530
3  AProj_AB_ESP20211123215423
```